# How to decode Base64 binary content as string, and then write it back on the HDD as binary content in WSH

Tags: javascript, base64, wsh

Basically I'm trying to save a small binary file in my JS file(as Base64 string). Then, during execution, to Base64 decode it and simply save it on the hard-drive.

I've been struggling for hours to find out what's wrong with my code, but all in all, once i write the decoded base64 back to the HDD, i see different bytes between the original file, and the encoded - decoded file.

I've also used the following [site](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to encrypt, decrypt the Base64ed string just to validate that the input / output is okay.

```
var base64string = "base64 string";
function Base64Encode(str) {
    if (/([^\u0000-\u00ff])/.test(str)) throw Error('String must be ASCII');

    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, bits, h1, h2, h3, h4, e=[], pad = '', c;

    c = str.length % 3;  // pad string to length of multiple of 3
    if (c > 0) { while (c++ < 3) { pad += '='; str += '\0'; } }
    // note: doing padding here saves us doing special-case packing for trailing 1 or 2 chars

    for (c=0; c<str.length; c+=3) {  // pack three octets into four hexets
        o1 = str.charCodeAt(c);
        o2 = str.charCodeAt(c+1);
        o3 = str.charCodeAt(c+2);

        bits = o1<<16 | o2<<8 | o3;

        h1 = bits>>18 & 0x3f;
        h2 = bits>>12 & 0x3f;
        h3 = bits>>6 & 0x3f;
        h4 = bits & 0x3f;

        // use hextets to index into code string
        e[c/3] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
    }
    str = e.join('');  // use Array.join() for better performance than repeated string appends

    // replace 'A's from padded nulls with '='s
    str = str.slice(0, str.length-pad.length) + pad;

    return str;
}

function Base64Decode(str) {
    if (!(/^[a-z0-9+/]+={0,2}$/i.test(str)) || str.length%4 != 0) throw Error('Not base64 string');

    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, d=[];

    for (var c=0; c<str.length; c+=4) {  // unpack four hexets into three octets
        h1 = b64.indexOf(str.charAt(c));
        h2 = b64.indexOf(str.charAt(c+1));
        h3 = b64.indexOf(str.charAt(c+2));
        h4 = b64.indexOf(str.charAt(c+3));

        bits = h1<<18 | h2<<12 | h3<<6 | h4;

        o1 = bits>>>16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits>>>8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;

        d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
        // check for padding
        if (h4 == 0x40) d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
        if (h3 == 0x40) d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
    }
    str = d.join('');  // use Array.join() for better performance than repeated string appends

    return str;
}


var base64decoded= Base64Decode(base64string);
var TextStream = WScript.CreateObject('ADODB.Stream');
TextStream.Type = 2;
.,TextStream.charSet = 'windows-1250';
TextStream.Open();
TextStream.WriteText(base64decoded);


var BinaryStream = WScript.CreateObject('ADODB.Stream');
BinaryStream.Type = 1;
BinaryStream.Open();
TextStream.Position = 0;
TextStream.CopyTo(BinaryStream);
BinaryStream.SaveToFile("C:\\file.bin", 2);
BinaryStream.Close();
```

[image: Difference between the original file and the decoded string once flushed to the disk]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i used the wrong charSet.

TextStream.charSet = 'iso-8859-1'; is the correct answer.